# UITableView loading before variables being set

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a label on a UITableView. When clicked it will refresh my tableview and set the top cell's height. When I am setting the cell height, I am checking if a certain variable is TRUE. If true it will show the large height, if false, the smaller height.

**At the time of cell height creation, my variable is always false. It is a member variable and its value is being set when the user clicks on the label.**

How can I make sure that the variable is set before the table refreshes?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat rowHeight = 0;
    if(indexPath.row > 0)
    {
        TweetCell *cell = (TweetCell*)[self tableView:tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        rowHeight = cell.totalHeight;
    }
    else {
        if (reloadProfile) {
            rowHeight = profileCellHeight;
        }
        else{
            rowHeight = reloadCellHeight;
        }
    }

    return rowHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to set the initial value of your variable in the `- (id)init` method of your class.

*edit*:  Try manually refreshing the table immediately after setting the variable, in the same method in which you are setting the variable.

Comment: What about manually refreshing the table immediately after setting the variable, in the same method in which you are setting the variable?

Comment: Sometimes the answer can be so simple. Thank you very much for your patience Isaac. You nailed it.